# want thread to complete before process executes

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, createprocessasuser

I'm creating a process as a User(`CreateProcessAsUser()`) to launch an application on the users screen. I need to somehow get a function to run on the user's screen before the application launches. My thought were to `CreateRemoteThread()` and put my function in here but this would happen after the `CreateProcessAsUser()` already launched the application.Any one advise? Thanks

Comment: It is. I had the function call before the createprocessasuser call but that function gets called in Session 0 which is hidden. I thought that by using a thread i could call the function in the users session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new application that executes your function and then executes the target application (which could be done using `CreateProcess()` as the new application was started via `CreateProcessAsUser()`).

Comment: Is there a way of bypassing the creation of another new application. Could I do the following:  use CreateProcessAsUser to create a process that does not launch an application, then assign a thread to this process that calls my function, then create another process(CreateProcessAsUser) with my original application ??

Comment: @user1881918: "create a process that does not launch an application" - A process is an application, do you mean interface? I would avoid `CreateRemoteThread` - what if the application you want to launch is 64 bit, and your application is 32 bit? You can't inject a thread. You should `CreateProcessAsUser` on the calling application (i.e. use `GetModuleFileName`), with a command line parameter that tells it to do your 'function', that way you only need one application, but it does two things.

Comment: yes i meant interface but that would run some exe which wouldnt be any use. Thanks thats cleared things up